# How long would it take to make a dns domain forward from one address to another?

Tags: website, dns, ip, forwarding, special-characters

Here's an example. We've got a Swedish train station service Webpage. "skanetrafiken.se"

What's strange is that you spell Skane with special character Å "Skåne" so what you would want is Skånetrafiken.se. Now the dilemma is that they point out that it would take very long to make Skånetrafiken.se to forward to the old address aka "skanetrafiken.se". They've owned the one with "å" since 2003. Still it's not working (error). Would it really have to take more then 5 min to make it forward to the page skanetrafiken.se? Maybe some one could explain it to me before I make a big fool of myself.

Comment: Just to clarify.. I'm interested in the time it would take to set it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That really depends on the type of change that is required.

If this is a [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) change, in effect making skanetrafiken.se and Skånetrafiken.se point to the same IP address, that may require some very small effort on the part of a professional. But if they need to request the change from their ISP, it can take much longer, and the change might take 48 hours to propagate through the Internet.

If all they need to do is to set up a home page that does the forwarding, then it is a very small project indeed, but with deployment and test it certainly will still take more than 5 minutes.

There are no 5 minutes projects in this domain, as one has to compare the different means, decide on the best one, set it up, deploy and test. The professionals involved may also be rather busy and have their own queue of requests. Especially if they make mistakes.